# How to copy files from AndroVM to PC?

Tags: android, virtualbox, androvm

I am currently playing with Android in virtual machine using AndroVM. My problem is that I can't copy files from the VM to my PC.
So far I've had no luck accessing or even finding USB devices from within AndroVM. I have set up a shared folder between the VM and host, I can see and interact with files placed in there from my host machine but I cannot copy files into there from the VM - it keeps bringing up a "Permission Denied" error.

If anyone can help me with copying files to either flash drive or shared folder from within AndroVM would be great.

Comment: Ok, so took me ages to figure something out. I didn't want to use Dropbox or similar due to time and MBs to upload files then download to my host system. USB didn't work for some reason, and shared folder only worked one way. 
The workaround I did find was by using ES File Explorer. So I set a folder on my computer with full sharing accesses, then in ES I went to Network > LAN and set up a new server using the IP of my local machine. After that, no trouble transferring files in and out of thee.

Hopefully this will help anyone else new to Android VMware.

Answer (score -2):

One can do it with the FTP client and server apps from [f-droid.org](http://f-droid.org/)

Some DSL modems have an FTP server to serve USB thumbdrives to the clients, which can be used.